# Was Trudeau's invocation of the Emergency Act legal?

Tags: canada, protests, civil-rights, state-of-emergency

On Monday, February 14, 2022, Justin Trudeau invoked the never-before-used [Emergencies Act](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/e-4.5/page-1.html) in response to the ongoing [Freedom Convoy Protests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_convoy_protest) across the country, including the series of border blockades that were observed.

The law, as written, defines a National Emergency as follows:

> For the purposes of this Act, a national emergency is an urgent and
> critical situation of a temporary nature that
>
> (a) seriously endangers the lives, health or safety of Canadians and is of such proportions
> or nature as to exceed the capacity or authority of a province to deal with it, or
>
> (b) seriously threatens the ability of the Government of Canada to preserve the sovereignty,
> security and territorial integrity of Canada
>
> and that cannot be effectively dealt with under any other law of
> Canada.

I recognize that whether or not points (a) and (b) apply to this protest is highly opinion based, so instead, I'm particularly focusing in on the last phrase:

> and that cannot be effectively dealt with under any other law of Canada.

This invocation came the day after [the primary blockade on the Ambassador bridge was cleared by the police](https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/windsor/windsor-ambassador-bridge-police-protest-1.6350120), after an injunction from the Ontario Supreme Court barred the blockades.

Furthermore, Albertan blockaders had [agreed to peacefully retreat from the ongoing protest at the Coutts border crossing](https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/police-hug-protesters-as-they-roll-out-from-coutts-alberta-border-crossing), and the [Highway 15 crossing in Surrey was cleared by police.](https://www.peacearchnews.com/news/multiple-people-arrested-at-pacific-highway-border-crossing-in-south-surrey/)

Given the effectiveness of the recent police and court actions of clearing blockades, how could the current situation still meet the criteria of an Emergency, and permit the use of the Emergency Act?

Comment: how is this different from https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/70777/why-was-the-emergencies-act-invoked-in-canada-with-regard-to-the-freedom-convoy ? And if it is strictly a question of legality, would this not be better on SE.Law?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to primarily a legal question, which would be better asked on law.se

Comment: The protesters have repeatedly reneged on a number of their "promises".  Are we suppose to take them seriously with their latest "promise"?  Premier Kennedy refuses to do anything other than try to make hay out of this illegal protest to put egg on the face of Trudeau, which he is already doing, like yourself, in accusing Trudeau of over reach.  Political games are being played by rogue politicians at the expense of Canadians.